# Accessing child's state from another child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with two children components.

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

Child1 has a textarea and is leveraging useState to set the value of the textarea into state; editor, setEditor.

Child2 has a button and when clicked I want to get the value of editor within Child1.

What is my best course of action to accomplish this?

I've tried creating a new context to wrap my Parent container in but am still struggling on how to actually get the editor value.

My other idea was to push the useState into the parent and pass the props down into Child1 -- but then this would mean my parent component re-renders every time a key is pressed within the textarea of Child1.

Comment: Move the state to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

> In React, sharing state is accomplished by moving it up to the closest
>   common ancestor of the components that need it. This is called
>   “lifting state up”.

Don't worry about the parent component re-rendering unless there's real concern to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to lift the state from child1 to the parent and then u can pass it as props to all the children you have. Hope you understand that